# Cant use pivot wider after grouping with count

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, plyr

Today, I used the `count()` with  `group_by()` and `summarise()` from the dplyr package. Here is the code:

```
dplyr::group_by(QUARTER, PROVINCE, DATE) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(COUNT = count(EDUCATION)) %>%
ungroup()
```

Here is what my `df` looks like after executing the code above:

```
Quarter    PROVINCE      DATE        COUNT.x        COUNT.freq

2020Q1   New-York       2020-01-07     1              30
2021Q1   New-York       2020-01-07     2              21
2020Q1   New-York       2020-01-07     3              55
2021Q1   New-York       2020-01-07     4              8
```

Note: I did not create `COUNT.x` and `COUNT.freq` myself! Now, I am trying to take the `COUNT.x` as columns and `COUNT.freq` as the values. This means `pivot_wider()` would be the solution here. However, after trying the following:

```
pivot_wider(df, names_from = COUNT.x, values_from = COUNT.freq)
```

It says `COUNT.x` and `COUNT.freq` do not exist:

```
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `COUNT.x` doesn't exist
```

Also, checking `names(df)` gives me:

```
[1] "QUARTER"  "PROVINCE" "DATE" "COUNT"
```

It does not include `COUNT.x` and `COUNT.freq`!

Anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you tried this small change using quotes? 

pivot_wider(df, names_from = 'COUNT.x', values_from = 'COUNT.freq')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `count` is being applied within `summarise` resulting in a data.frame/tibble column.  It should be outside i.e.

```
dplyr::count(df, QUARTER, PROVINCE, DATE, EDUCATION)
```

---

If we are using the OP's code, it is not a regular data.frame column.  We need to reinvoke `data.frame` to flatten the columns

```
out <- df %>% dplyr::group_by(QUARTER, PROVINCE, DATE) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(COUNT = count(EDUCATION)) %>%
ungroup()
out1 <- do.call(data.frame, out)
```